# Confused with java exceptions

Tags: java, exception

### EDIT:

What about this (the socket is an example it can be some other class) ?

```
InetAddress iNetAdd = InetAddress.getByName(someIp);
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(somePort, 50, iNetAdd);
```

It can throw a BindException that can be (e.getMessage()):

1. Address already in use: JVM_Bind
2. Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

if i have to treat [1] and [2] in different way how i can catch them ?

example:

```
if [1] 
  set somePort++ and retry 
else if [2] 
  print cant use someIp to listen
```

---

### ORIGINAL:

Maybe i'm missing something but (example):

1. `ServerSocket.accept()` can throw a `SocketException` (and others)
2. That `SocketException` can be different things (ie. connection close, reset, etc...)

If I have to do different things depending on the specific error, is correct to do something like this ?

```
catch (SocketException e)
{
    if (e.getMessage().equals("this"))
    {
        doStuff();
    }
    else if (e.getMessage().equals("that"))
    {
        eatPotatoes();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is dangerous to rely upon message contents.

Comment: SocketException does have subclasses. In those cases you can catch them separately or do if (e instanceof ConnectException)...

Comment: Re your edit, 'cannot assign requested address' is fundamentally a programming error resulting from using an invalid or non-local IP address. So it shouldn't happen at runtime once you weed out your programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. `ServerSocket.accept()` can throw a `SocketException` (and others)

No, it can throw `IOException` or any subclass.

> 2. That `SocketException` can be different things (ie. connection close, reset, etc...)

No, it can't be any of those in the case of `ServerSocket.accept()`. It can really only be `SocketTimeoutException` if you set a timeout, or `SocketException: socket closed`, or a TCP protocol error.

The correct way to handle subclasses of any exception, in this case `IOException`, is to catch them separately if you're going to handle them separately. In the case of `accept()`, however, all exceptions except `SocketTimeoutException` are fatal, so all you can do is close the `ServerSocket` and exit the accept loop. So all you need is two `catch` statements: one for `SocketTimeoutException` and one for `IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

> ServerSocket.accept() can throw a SocketException (and others)

these are the only possible exceptions that [**`accept()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) method could throw:

`IOException` - if an I/O error occurs when waiting for a connection.

`SecurityException` - if a security manager exists and its `checkAccept` method doesn't allow the operation.

`SocketTimeoutException` - if a timeout was previously set with `setSoTimeout` and the timeout has been reached.

`IllegalBlockingModeException` - if this socket has an associated channel, the channel is in non-blocking mode, and there is no connection ready to be accepted.

> If I have to do different things depending on the specific error, is
>   correct to do something like this?

No, you shouldn't proceed with your approach, as that is not a good practice, you'd rather have separate catch statements to handle the different type of exceptions.

Comment: Why use instanceof instead of catching the types?

Comment: It can also throw *subclasses* of `IOException`, and `BindException` is just one of them.

Answer (score -1):

If i guess true. You need sub class SocketException. It same:

```
}catch(SocketException e){
        if(e instanceof BindException){

        }else if(e instanceof ConnectException){

        }else if(e instanceof ConnectionResetException){

        }else if(e instanceof NoRouteToHostException){

        }else if(e instanceof PortUnreachableException){

        }else{

        }
    }
```

Hope help you!

Comment: Instead of this atrocity you should use separate `catch` blocks, but the real problem is that `ServerSocket.accept()` does not throw any of `ConnectException`, `BindException`, `NoRouteToHostException`, or `PortUnreachableException`. The latter indeed is for UDP only.